# Python testing .jws endpoint

Tags: python, web-services, automation, java-web-start, web-api-testing

I have a soapui project that uses a jws endpoint.

I want to try to automate and run the api testing outside of soapui.

Is there a python module that can test jws endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the requests module to post the xml requests:

example:

```
requests.post(
    '<url>.jws',data='<Webservice XML requests>',
     headers={'content-type':'text/xml'}
)
```